# Site with declension of words

Tags: словарь

Is there a site that contains the declensions for all cases of russian words and that shows which vowel has the accent? Is there an equivalent to Duden German dictionary, but for Russian?

I have used Wiktionary, which has accurate information most of the times, but for some irregular words I cannot verify if the declensions are correct or not.

Comment: Failing Wiktionary, try this website: http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx It can generate a declension table for any word, including non-dictionary words. It even does multiword phrases e.g. Нижний Новгород, водитель автобуса, Александр Сергеевич Пушкин.

Comment: asking for specific resource is off-topic here, you can try your like at language learners stack or software rec - but anyway to make this particular question on-topic there its should be edited I guess.

Comment: try this http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on seems good, stressed vowel is highlighted, enter a word аnd hit ГРАММАТИКА button, further menu is under the hamburger button in the upper left hand corner

Comment: I use wiktionary.org